# Teradata JDBC executeBatch errorhandling

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I am inserting data into a teradata table using executeBatch method. Currently if one insert in the batch fails all the other inserts in the batch also fails and no records end up being inserted. How can I change this behaviour to let the other inserts in the batch succeed if any inserts fails and the some ability to track the rejected records.

PS: I have ensured that TMODE is set to TERA and autocommit enabled.

UPDATE:

target table definition.

```
CREATE SET TABLE mydb.mytable ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      col1 INTEGER,
      col2 VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX ( col1 );
```

Below is the sample scala code. As you can see, this batch contains 5 insert statements. The First insert is set to fail because it is trying to insert null into an not null field (col2). The other 4 inserts dont have any issues and should succeed. But as you can see from below all 5 inserts in the batch failed. Is there any way we can make other inserts succeed?. As stated above tmode is tera and autocommit is enabled. if there is no way other than re-submitting all failed queries individually then we would have to reduce the batch size and settle for lower throughput.

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:teradata://teradata-server/mydb,tmode=TERA","username","password")
val insertSQL =  "INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES (?,?)"
val stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL)


stmt.setInt(1,1)
stmt.setNull(2,Types.VARCHAR)  // Inserting Null here. This insert will fail
stmt.addBatch()

stmt.setInt(1,2)
stmt.setString(2,"XXX")
stmt.addBatch()

stmt.setInt(1,3)
stmt.setString(2,"YYY")
stmt.addBatch()

stmt.setInt(1,4)
stmt.setString(2,"ZZZ")
stmt.addBatch()

stmt.setInt(1,5)
stmt.setString(2,"ABC")
stmt.addBatch()

try {
val res = stmt.executeBatch()
println(res.mkString(","))
}
catch {
 case th: BatchUpdateException => {
        println(th.getUpdateCounts().mkString(","))
 }
}
```

#### Result

-3,-3,-3,-3,-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Teradata's [JDBC manual](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html):

> Beginning with Teradata Database 13.10 and Teradata JDBC Driver
>   13.00.00.16, PreparedStatement batch execution can return individual success and error conditions for each parameter set.
>
> An application using the PreparedStatement executeBatch method must
>   have a catch-block for BatchUpdateException and the application must
>   examine the error code returned by the BatchUpdateException
>   getErrorCode method.

[PreparedStatement BatchUpdateException Handling](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#CCHJHFDI)

[Execute a multi-statement request using a PreparedStatement batch request and demonstrates the handling of the PreparedStatement BatchUpdateException](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20706JD.java.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked up the example and have updated my question for a follow up question..

Comment: @mig-foxbat: Sorry, I can't tell what's wrong with your code as I'm not a Java-developer.

Comment: Thanks Dieter.. so the final thing I wanted to confirm is that if my batch of 10 records fails due to one records, none of the records are commited and I will have to re-apply each records individually.